# Is there any demo to insert a new record into a table with identity primary key using Subsonic 3?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Is there any demo to insert a new record into a table with identity primary key using Subsonic 3?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create DAL object
2. Assign values to all properties except primary key property
3. Call Save()

Subsonic takes care of the identity keys itself you need not worry.

Answer (score 2):

http://subsonicproject.com/docs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has made it to the current version, but Rob showed an example to use a lambda expression to insert a record:

```
db.Insert.Into<Northwind.Region>(x => x.RegionID, x => x.RegionDescription)
        .Values(6, "Hawaii").Execute();
```

http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-3-0-preview-1-linq-has-landed/